# Python pdb change variable confusion

Tags: python, unit-testing, debugging, transactions, sqlalchemy

During debugging of the unittest of my Python web application using SQLAlchemy, the uber persistent user object dropped my jaw --

```
> myapp/views/signup.py(73)signup_view()
-> user = model.User(user_name=user_name, email=email, password=password)
(Pdb) n
(Pdb) user
<pweb.models.User object at 0xbbb20ec>
(Pdb) user = None
(Pdb) user
<pweb.models.User object at 0xbbb20ec>     <!-- !!!??? -->

(Pdb) user2 = model.User(user_name=user_name, email=email, password=password)
(Pdb) user2
<pweb.models.User object at 0xbbb2f0c>
(Pdb) user2 = None
(Pdb) user2
(Pdb)
```

Similar behaviour can not be observed in stand-alone trivial script --

```
(Pdb) l
  1   if __name__ == '__main__':
  2       user = 1
  3       import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
  4  ->     pass
[EOF]
(Pdb) user
1
(Pdb) user = 2
(Pdb) user
2
```

What should the rationale be in the first example? Could it be related to the mid of transaction that is behind [Python unittest (using SQLAlchemy) does not write/update database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533245/python-unittest-using-sqlalchemy-does-not-write-update-database)?

Comment: Can you post the definition of the User class?

Comment: Are you using Python 2.6 or lower? Might be related to a bug there, and therefore a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912820/how-do-i-change-a-value-while-debugging-python-with-pdb/7912888